# Script not Clearing cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm sorry for asking this I've been doing so much reading. The script does finish but its not clearing selected cells.  What did I do wrong?  Please help?

```
   // Display a dialog box with a message and "Yes" and "No" buttons.
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi( );
    var response = ui.alert('Are you sure you want to continue?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

   // Process the user's response.
   if (response == ui.Button.YES) {
   Logger.log('The user clicked "Yes."');
   } else {
   Logger.log('The user clicked "No" or the dialog\'s close button.');
   }  
   function clearRange() {
  //replace 'Sheet1' with your actual sheet name
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('LOAD ASSIGNMENT');
  sheet.getRange('A4:L120').clearContent();
   }
```

Comment: how are you getting this code to run? Are you seeing the message box? is there more code that you have not posted?

Comment: which cells are you trying to clear? In your statement above your code you mention selected cells where your code has given cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Warning: unused function clearRange.`
call it :) 
after you defined the function, you are missing:
`clearRange();`

Comment: Thank you, yes the box pops up and asks to continue.   Trying to clear a4 to L120

Comment: Just got home from work, do I just delete that line?

Comment: you have only defined a function called clearRange, but no code calls it. You need to catch up with using javascript.

Answer (score 1):

As everyone else has eluded to, you've made the function clearRange, but no where do you activate/call it. Thought I'd include the altered code so you can see what is meant by calling the function.

```
    function myFunction() {

    function clearRange() {
  //replace 'Sheet1' with your actual sheet name
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('LOAD ASSIGNMENT');
  sheet.getRange('A4:L120').clearContent();
   }


   // Display a dialog box with a message and "Yes" and "No" buttons.
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi( );
    var response = ui.alert('Are you sure you want to continue?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

   // Process the user's response.
   if (response == ui.Button.YES) {

     // Just to clarify, you have created the clearRange function. I've moved it above. But no where do you say run it.
     // Below is the function being CALLED if the response to the prompt is YES


  clearRange();  


   Logger.log('The user clicked "Yes."');
   } else {
   Logger.log('The user clicked "No" or the dialog\'s close button.');
   }  


}
```